# Remove or resize icon-preview in column view in Finder

Tags: finder, preview, icon

When working I often have a small Finder window in the corner of my screen, in column view. The preview of the icon is so large that it forces the file properties info (ie. file size, creation dates etc) off the bottom of the screen so you have to scroll to see it.

Is there any setting to resize the max-width of the icon preview, or to disable it entirely so you only see the file properties?

Now:

[image: icon is big]

Desired View:

[image: no icon]

Thanks for any help